# How to insert numbers with decimal point in Postgresql database table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, decimal, sqldatatypes

Numeric datatype doesn't accept decimal points in numbers and PgAdmin 4.2 don't have  decimal data type. I want to add percentage numbers like 4.8 and latitude, longitudes something like -89.03177649999999 this. Which is the best data type in postgresql for this king of numbers. PgAdmin only allows numeric datatype to use for numbers. If I add this numbers with numeric data type it throws errors.

Comment: The `numeric` data type certainly accepts decimal points. Please edit the question and provide an SQL statement and error message to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely insert values with a decimal point into a numeric column:

```
create table data (nr decimal);
insert into data 
values 
(-89.03177649999999);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/VQB54123

Comment: greate. I tried creating table with decimal, its accepting the values. When I used gui for create table, there is no decimal data type option available in data types list for columns.

Comment: @Gauri: `numeric` is an alias for `decimal` - does that "GUI" offer `numeric`?

Comment: Yes. GUI offers numeric.